# Restore an oracle dmp file

Tags: oracle, import

I've been given an oracle DMP file that was created on a solaris system which I need to restore to a windows system.

I've created the DB with the correct blocksize, but when I try and do the restore it complains that it can't create the folders.

I've created the folder in Windows and in my imp command i've specified the directory, but it still fails.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Here is the full error message

```
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1119 encountered
ORA-01119: error in creating database file '/home/oradata/d_test01/tools01.dbf'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
```

What do i need to specify in the restore command to change the restore location.  As I said previously the backup was created on a solaris based system and I have trying to restore it on Windows

All i've been given is the dmp file.  It was created by a consultant who no longer does work for us.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Show us a screenshot or the exact error message.

Comment: Are you sure the dump was taken using is a legacy tool `exp`. Could it be a dump taken using DataPump (`expdp`)? In that case you need to use `impdp` to import it. And `imp` doesn't "create folders" - so it's totally unclear what you are doing

Comment: show the logfile of the export or expdp session that created the dmp file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full database import which also includes tablespace definitions. Find out from the original Solaris database what are all the target tablespace names and sizes. Pre-create the tablespaces manually using the datafile paths of your choice (`C:\data\`) before performing the import. You will see `IMP-00015: following statement failed because the object already exists: your tablespace` which you can ignore.

Comment: Thanks for your email.  We no longer have the server....just the dmp file....sorry if I didnt make that clear.....

Comment: Use your imagination :)

Comment: You need to either precreate the tablespaces with the same names, or make sure that the server you're importing to has the same directory structure so that the tablespaces can be created by the import program.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my own experience, I have solved the issue `ora-39006 internal error while impdp` with the following solution:

1. Delete existing TBSpace folder in 'C:\Users\app\TBSpace', delete all files;
   but if you do not have TBSpace yet, please create it.
2. You should create:

   - Tablespace for data
   - Tablespace for indexes
   - tablespace for mviews
   - Tablespace for temp
     This is also based on your database/system requirements.
     Like this example:

     ```
     `CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE MSSYS_TS_DATA DATAFILE   
     'C:\Users\app\TBSpace\MSSYS_TS_DATA.DBF'     
         SIZE 5M AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 5M MAXSIZE 100000M  
         LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT  
         EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE  
         BLOCKSIZE 8K  
         SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO  
         FLASHBACK ON;
     ```
3. Create users, grant and alter users to tables
4. Create directory in:

   - create or replace directory SWIFT_FOLDER_IN as 'C:\Users\app\SWIFT_IN';
   - create or replace directory SWIFT_FOLDER_OUT as 'C:\Users\app\SWIFT_OUT';
5. Grant permission to:

   - Grant read,write on directory SWIFT_FOLDER_IN to MSsys;
   - Grant read,write on directory SWIFT_FOLDER_OUT to MSsys;
6. Grant execute to tables
    example:

   ```
   grant execute on MSsys.MScore to MScode;
   ```
7. Compile, example:

   ```
   begin
       DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'MScode');
   end;
   ```